# Toolbar customization palette dosn't display default image

Tags: customization, nstoolbar

I have an application which calls `runCustomizationPalette`.

In my application I add my tools to the NSToolbar and then I set one of them not to be displayed by default.

The toolbar is set to display both image and text.

When I run the application everything works as expected - the tool that turned off is not displayed. But when I call the function, palette is displayed, but the tool that is turned off shows in the palette with `Text Only` - no image is displayed.

When I remove the default button removal and display all the buttons in the toolbar and display the customization palette - everything is displayed as it should.

My question would be - what is controlling the display of the images in the `Customization Palette`?

TIA!!

EDIT:

This is the code for toolbar creation:

```
    NSToolbar* tb =  [[wxNSToolbar alloc] initWithIdentifier:cfidentifier.AsNSString()];
    [tb setAllowsUserCustomization:YES];
    [tb setAutosavesConfiguration:YES];
    NSToolbarDisplayMode mode = NSToolbarDisplayModeDefault;
    NSToolbarSizeMode displaySize = NSToolbarSizeModeSmall;

    if ( style & NOICONS )
        mode = NSToolbarDisplayModeLabelOnly;
    else if ( style & TEXT )
        mode = NSToolbarDisplayModeIconAndLabel;
    else
        mode = NSToolbarDisplayModeIconOnly;

    [tb setDisplayMode:mode];
    [tb setSizeMode:displaySize];
```

What am I missing? It should be something really simple like some ind of style...

Comment: How is the toolbar created? Post a [mre] please.

Comment: @Willeke, sorry for the delay. I was busy with life. I put the code in for NSToolbar creation function. I think it is some simple and stupid.

Comment: If the toolbar is created in code then it needs a delegate. How is the toolbar item created?

Comment: @Willeke, yes it has a delegate. I will update the OP tonight with the code.

Comment: @Willeke, should I set this property for it to show up: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstoolbaritem/1527749-image?language=objc? Documentation doesn't mention it...

Comment: @Willeke, I solved it!! I had to add the image property and set the image to the button. I removed the setting the image because it was crashing, but not anymore - I added the image property to the tool. Thank you for the support, even if its just moral. ;-)